# How can I do this using CSS?

Tags: html, css

i have a image who are look like a transparent but working as a zebra table like chase and i want to apply a color  `rgba(12,120,234,0.4);`

how i can show the image and color both

```
background-image: url('Images/embedded_bg.png');
background-color: rgba(12,120,234,0.4);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine them with the [background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) property:

```
background: rgba(12,120,234,0.4) url('Images/embedded_bg.png') repeat 0 0;
```

[In action here](http://jsfiddle.net/rYvyN/).

Comment: first i need a background repeated and second i want both color and image. by your code image work but color not.

Comment: Changing to repeat isn't a problem and you'll only get both the colour and image showing if your background image is a transparent .png.  If you check the example link I just added you'll see it works (background-image overlays background-color on the same element).

Answer (score 0):

i got the sollution is here

```
body
{

   background-image: url('Images/embedded_bg.png');
   width:1000px;
}
#main
{
    background-color: rgba(12,120,234,0.4);
}
```